# Redis in django-rest-framework in get method

Tags: caching, redis, get, django-rest-framework

I am using redis in django restframe work and geting problem in get method

I have save data for multiple users with different keys

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def abc(request):
    key  = request.META['HTTP_KEY']

    if  cache.get(key) == None:
        print('create a cache and return data ');
        cache.set(key,key,timeout =100)
        return JsonResponse({'data': cache.get(key) })
    else:
        print('return data from cache')
        return JsonResponse({'data': cache.get(key) })
```

first time it is creating a cache and return a data and when I hit next time with different key it will return same data event it is not execute the if else condition/not printing print command. I thing it create url base cache, how can solve this problem?

I hit with key "a" first time and it return me = a and print "create a cache and return data"

next time I hit with with key b, it return me old data "a" and  not print any line 'create a cache and return data '/'return data from cache'

Comment: First, JsonResponse is pure django, nothing to do with DRF. Second, being that you probably didn't paste the relevant part of your code. what does your full view like ?

Comment: My question is simple when i am sending different key. Why I am getting same result which I have set first time in cache. This is only happen in 'get' method. If I change get to post then it will work fine.

Comment: This code snippet should not work with POST (you should get a 405) nor should it return anything without a print statement. Did you setup FetchFromCacheMiddleware in your settings ? If so, you'll have to play with the vary header (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
from django.views.decorators.vary import vary_on_headers

@vary_on_headers('key')
```

'key' Please menstion your header key here

[Using Very header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers)